# Nuxt 3 Deployment with Lambda (Docker Image) Configuration

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am using Index.mjs with Server.mjs to render the code on Serverless but it doesn't work with Nuxt 3. Any new changes required to render the Vue 3 app on Lambda with Nitro server.

Any suggestions on how to deploy Nuxt 3 and what should the entry point for the server. We have been using Index handler in the past.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.